# How to test different font sizes (dynamic type) on the watch?

Tags: ios, xcode, accessibility, watchkit, apple-watch

Apple watch supports [Dynamic Type](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TransitionGuide/AppearanceCustomization.html) (e.g. by using text styles such as body or footnote). Assuming I have labels that use these custom text styles, how can I test their behavior on the simulator?

On an iPhone simulator, I can launch Settings > General > Larger Text and adjust the slider to see how my app looks depending on different font sizes.

How can I do the equivalent for my Apple Watch app running on the simulator?

Answer (score 1):

No possibility yet. Just set it to bold and some points larger in your storyboard to test it.

Sorry mate...

Edit: I just ran over this:
https://developer.apple.com/watchkit/

Download the `Apple Watch Design Resources` there and have a look at Guides > Guide-Type. There you will have the right font sizes and weights for Dynamic Type.

Answer (score 0):

You could change text size on apple watch simulator - Settings > Display & Brightness > Text Size.