# How to use alternate font weights (e.g. "short") in a WKInterfaceLabel?

Tags: ios, watchkit, uifont, dynamic-type-feature, wkinterfacelabel

In Apple's [Apple Watch Design Resources](https://developer.apple.com/watchkit/), there is a document called **Alternate Font Weights and Italicizations**. In it, it shows examples of what the default font looks like with different attributes such as **Italic**, **Emphasized**, and **Short** applied to it.

Assume I want to use a font that looks exactly like the "Short" example.

1. Is there any way to choose this font and style via the storyboard for a label?
2. In code, how would I set a label to use this font and style?

Answer (score 3):

In an iOS project, I tried modifying the body font (`UIFontTextStyleBody`) to include `UIFontDescriptorTraitTightLeading`. When I read the `fontAttributes` properties,  it reports the `NSFontNameAttribute` as `.AppleSystemUIShortBody` (the original value is `.AppleSystemUIBody`).

From this, I was able to figure out Apple's terms:

```
+------------+-----------------------------------+------------------------------+---------------------------------+
|    Term    |  UIFontDescriptorSymbolicTraits   |     NSFontNameAttribute      |    NSCTFontUIUsageAttribute     |
+------------+-----------------------------------+------------------------------+---------------------------------+
|            | (none)                            | .AppleSystemUIBody           | UICTFontTextStyleBody           |
| Italic     | UIFontDescriptorTraitItalic       | .AppleSystemUIItalicBody     | UICTFontTextStyleItalicBody     |
| Emphasized | UIFontDescriptorTraitBold         | .AppleSystemUIEmphasizedBody | UICTFontTextStyleEmphasizedBody |
| Short      | UIFontDescriptorTraitTightLeading | .AppleSystemUIShortBody      | UICTFontTextStyleShortBody      |
| Tall?      | UIFontDescriptorTraitLooseLeading | .AppleSystemUISpliceTallBody | UICTFontTextStyleTallBody       |
+------------+-----------------------------------+------------------------------+---------------------------------+
```

If you attempt to do the same thing with `UIFontDescriptorTraitExpanded`, `UIFontDescriptorTraitCondensed`, `UIFontDescriptorTraitVertical`, `UIFontDescriptorTraitUIOptimized`, and then read the `fontAttributes`, it returns the same value as the Body style. If you try the same thing with `UIFontDescriptorTraitMonoSpace`, it returns a `nil` dictionary.

Therefore, in an Apple Watch project, you *should* be able to use the **Body Short Emphasized** font like so:

```
/*1*/ UIFontDescriptor *fontDescriptor = [UIFontDescriptor preferredFontDescriptorWithTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleBody];
/*2*/ fontDescriptor = [fontDescriptor fontDescriptorWithSymbolicTraits:UIFontDescriptorTraitTightLeading | UIFontDescriptorTraitBold];
/*3*/ UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithDescriptor:fontDescriptor size:0];
/*4*/ [label setAttributedText:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:text attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: font}]];
```

I say "should" because there are two bugs in play here:

- On line 2, `UIFontDescriptorTraitTightLeading` is being specified, yet this trait is ignored on both watch simulators. Bold and italic work just fine.
- On line 3, since `size` is set to `0`, it gets its value from the `UIFontDescriptorSizeAttribute` in `fontDescriptor` <sup>[[1]](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIFont_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIFont/fontWithDescriptor:size:)</sup>. The problem is that on a 38mm device, there is a bug with both `+[UIFontDescriptor preferredFontDescriptorWithTextStyle:]` and `-[UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:]` (used on **line 1**). When the user [doesn't customize the font size](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29426178/35690), both methods return `16`, when clearly `15` should be chosen on the 38mm device. (You can verify this by placing a label on a storyboard, assigning it the **Body** size, and visually comparing it to a label that sets its size to 15 manually.)

Note: I am running Xcode 6.2.