# UIFont "short" style

Tags: ios, swift, ios9, uifont

Using CSS property to set SF font in a WebView I use - `-apple-system-short-body`

Trying to implement this font programatically I do not find this style. I believe this is related somehow to tracking but I could not figure this out.

**EDIT**

I know I can use -

```
UIFont.preferredFontForTextStyle(UIFontTextStyleBody)
```

But this will be equivalent to `-apple-system-body` while I looks for `-apple-system-short-body`

Any help?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29503926/4151918), Short corresponds to the `UIFontDescriptorTraitTightLeading` [symbolic trait](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIFontDescriptor_Class/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIFontDescriptorSymbolicTraits).

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for